# Drupal 6 Fatal error on profile view

Tags: profile, drupal-6

D6, Civi 4.6.7

I've ceated a directory profile of organisations. I can see the directory list, but when trying to 'view' the details of an organisation I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'CRM_Profile_Page_View' not found in /home/xxxx/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php on line 297
```

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have recently upgraded, make sure you clear your caches, including the contents of /sites/.../files/civicrm/templates_c/*